# How to modify a DataTable in order to get parts of DB results from a controller via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, datatable

I have a controller that returns really large amount of data. I pass this data to a Twig template, make a `<table>` from it, and then I call .dataTable() on this table element.

This is not efficient, because it downloads ALL the data at once and passes it to the page source...

I want to modify it in a way that will enable the DataTable to use ajax to download and display first 500 records, then when user clicks on "more" button, it will download and display next 500 records and so on. Is there a way to achieve this using dataTables?

This is the method for retrieving records (it is later called in a controller and results are passed directly to Twig):

```
    public function getLoginsHistory(){
    $document_manager = $this
        ->container
        ->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getManager();

    $query_builder = $document_manager
        ->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:LoginEvent')
        ->sort('timestamp', 'desc')
        ->find();

    $query = $query_builder->getQuery();
    $entries = $query->execute();
    return $entries;

}
```

This is what happens in Twig:

```
        <div class="table-scrollable">
            <table id="login_history_table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                {% for entry in entries %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{  entry.userID}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ entry.event==1 ? '<span class="label label-sm label-success"> Logged in </span>' : '<span class="label label-sm label-danger"> Logged out </span>' }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{  entry.timestamp|date }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And then in my js file i just call

```
$("#login_history_table").dataTable();
```

So is there a way to achieve what I have described?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action which would answer on ajax calls (two arguments must be provided - currentOffset and maxRecords (if you need more/less than 500)) and call the query for login history with arguments from request, query method would look smth like this:

```
public function getLoginsHistory($offset = 0, $maxRecords = 500){
    $document_manager = $this
        ->container
        ->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getManager();

    $query_builder = $document_manager
        ->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:LoginEvent')
        ->sort('timestamp', 'desc')
        ->limit($maxRecords)
        ->skip($offset)
        ->find();

    $query = $query_builder->getQuery();
    $entries = $query->execute();
    return $entries;

}
```

See [Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#limiting-results) about results limiting;

Comment: I understand, however how would the ajax call from datatables work? I've never done datatables by ajax and how will datatables know what arguments to pass to the ajax request?

Comment: I had never worked with dataTables, but looked a little at it now: as I see, you can catch pageChange event or click event on page number, than it would be easy - you must call `$.ajax{}` where data section would look like: `data: {offset: (page-1)*rowsCount, maxRows: rowsCount}` where `page-1` is the page number on which user clicked minus one (for actual results) and rowsCount is the number of rows on page or some other number. And, maybe, it would be easier with dataTables ajax loading of data. Maybe it could load it paginated.